# JSONP request handling using jquery or plain JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am building a weather app using AllWeatherMap api with HTML,CSS and JS. The weather details provided is in JSONP format. I read that jquery handles such request in the background. But My webapp don't need any jquery library. So, should I use jquery for the request handling or I will use plain JS to solve cross origin problem. 
Here is my call:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=201310,IN&appid=[MY_ID]
```

Response:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 77.57,
    "lat": 28.45
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 721,
      "main": "Haze",
      "description": "haze",
      "icon": "50n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 306.15,
    "pressure": 999,
    "humidity": 66,
    "temp_min": 306.15,
    "temp_max": 306.15
  },
  "visibility": 4000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.5,
    "deg": 110
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 40
  },
  "dt": 1531841400,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 7809,
    "message": 0.0037,
    "country": "IN",
    "sunrise": 1531785804,
    "sunset": 1531835291
  },
  "id": 200124150,
  "name": "Greater Noida",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Why don't we bother of some api's about the cross-domain issue like this one:

```
https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json
```

The json of above url is accessed without any issue.

Comment: You can use plain JS if you prefer, there's no real difference other than jQuery is syntactically more succinct. Also note that that response is not JSONP - it's plain JSON. I'm not sure what cross-origin problems you're referring to, as the OpenWeatherMap API returns CORS, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jwvnL5ez/

Comment: ok...Thanks for the fiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to try the fetch api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch instead of jquery, especially if jquery is not used in the project anywhere else (because there is just no need). With fetch api you can easily handle json responses, as well as CORS problems & so.